# create mailto hyperlink that will open in outlook with a hyperlink in the body

Tags: html, hyperlink, outlook, mailto

Here's my scenario:

I'm trying to embed a hyperlink in the body of an email that will be generated using the mailto hyperlink.  So I will have something like this:

```
<a href="mailto:someemail@test.com?subject=Email Subject&body=Click 
<a href=%22http://www.google.com%22>Here</a> to go to google.com">Click Here to open 
Outlook and with generated email</a>
```

The problem is, this scenario will open outlook but the email will actually appear as:

```
Click <a href="http://www.google.com">Here</a> to go to google.com
```

the http://www.google.com will be clickable in the email but the anchor tag will also show up and it is ugly.

I'm not sure if this is possible, but can I somehow create this hyperlink in a way that Outlook won't catch the URL address and automatically create the anchor tag around it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't do this. See [the specification for mailto: URIs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068#section-2), which says:

> The special  "body" indicates that the associated 
> is the body of the message.  The "body" field value is intended to
> contain the content for the first **text/plain body part of the
> message**.  The "body" pseudo header field is primarily intended for
> the generation of short text messages for automatic processing (such
> as "subscribe" messages for mailing lists), not for general MIME
> bodies.  Except for the encoding of characters based on UTF-8 and
> percent-encoding, no additional encoding (such as e.g., base64 or
> quoted-printable; see [RFC2045]) is used for the "body" field value.
> As a consequence, header fields related to message encoding (e.g.,
> Content-Transfer-Encoding) in a 'mailto' URI are irrelevant and MUST
> be ignored.  The "body" pseudo header field name has been registered
> with IANA for this special purpose (see Section 8.2).

Comment: Excellent david, please tell me how did you find the specification?  When I google "html mailto specification" this one doesn't come up

Comment: I searched for "rfc mailto:" and then picked the highest numbered one in the results (since it has undergone a number of revisions and I didn't want an old one that didn't define the extra headers). It has nothing to do with HTML though, so you including that keyword probably threw the results off.